# What is the `ia:` properties in Open Graph protocol?

Tags: meta-tags, open-graph-protocol

In [this sharing debugger result](https://www.facebook.com/tools/debug/), I notice some strange properties:

- `ia:markup_url`
- `ia:markup_url_dev`
- `ia:rules_url`
- `ia:rules_url_dev`

There is no documentation in [The Open Graph protocol](https://ogp.me/). What are they for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search shows me that those are related to Facebook Instant Articles.

It looks like the functionality/service is no longer available as of April 2023. Maybe the debugger is still leveraging the meta tags for other services...

Comment: What's the keyword you use to Google? I can't figure out one

Comment: I just searched for `ia:markup_url` and it came up with some documentation. Then I just quickly skimmed some of them to be sure.

Comment: Weird. I did the same but the result was just code from other projects. None of them referred to anything useful